# Check what files a program reads from a computer (C++)

Tags: c++, file

I have a program that reads files (given to it by the user) from the computer and performs operations on these files. However, the program isn't working. I input a valid file with a valid path and the program says it is reading this valid file, however, it doesn't find the files. I have verified that the method I use to read the files works.

So, this prompts my question. Is it possible for a C++ program to track what files are being read by a specific program, and tell me the path it is trying to read?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: On Unix-like systems one typically uses [strace](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) which produces a lot of output logging all system calls, among them calls to open a file. But at your level that's probably overkill and it will be too difficult to extract the necessary information. Advice: (1) Use absolute paths. (2) Make sure to use double backslashes on Windows, or use raw strings like `R"C:\temp\x.txt"`. (3) Check the status of streams, and/or check the return value of functions.

Comment: @DavidGrayson Linux- Kali linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Linux, the `strace` utility is the answer (as mentioned by Peter in a comment).  You probably have it installed already, so just run `strace your_program_name` and you can see *all* the system calls the program is running, and their arguments and return codes.  You should focus on the `open` calls.

Comment: Also, check out `lsof` if you want to see all the files currently open by a program :-)

Comment: I got this to work, thanks so much. However, I was wondering if this is the best way to do this, as I heard that strace slows down the execution of your program and now when I go to run it on my other program which takes a long time to get to the file open call, it simply takes too long to be feasible for this project. Are there any alternatives that you would reccomend?

Comment: Try `strace -e open`; that will supposedly only print the `open` calls.  If that is still too slow, you should probably add debugging code  (e.g. `printf`) to the places in the code where you are opening the files.  `strace` is definitely just for debugging and development; I wouldn't leave it on during production / normal operation.

Comment: Thanks, that worked a lot faster!!!